# Can PHP maps be made less verbose?

Tags: php, clojure

I just ran into this simple bit of PHP code:

```
$html = Html::openElement( 'tr' );
foreach ( $this->headers as $header ) {
    $html .= $header->toHtml();
}
$html .= Html::closeElement( 'tr' );
return $html;
```

And I thought to myself "this is rather imperative, let's get rid of the state". The result:

```
return Html::openElement( 'tr' )
    . implode( '', array_map(
        function( HtmlSerializable $header ) {
                return $header->toHtml();
        },
        $this->headers
    ) )
    . Html::closeElement( 'tr' );
```

Is there no more sane (less verbose) way to do the string concatenation and mapping of the method? It's very verbose compared to say Clojure

```
(str (map (memfn toHtml) headers))
```

Comment: Perhaps consider something like [currying](http://zaemis.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/currying-in-php.html)

Comment: What would you curry in this case? Either way, it seems to me this approach comes with at least two downsides: pollution of a bigger scope with the function definition and the inability of tools to provide useful static code analysis for it.

Comment: Well one thing you could curry would be the arguments for your string concatenation

Comment: Indeed. Or I could create a `str` function that has `return implode( func_get_args() );`. No real magic needed, though both approaches force me to create a pile of such functions on top of PHP, which I'm looking to avoid.